# Can I Read/Write google spreadsheets using GET/POST methods

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4

I want to know is it possible to read/write google spreadsheets using GET/POST methods with `UIWebView`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two Google API's that might interest you:

1. [Google Spreadsheets](http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/) - Used read/manipulate spreadsheet data
2. [Google Documents](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/developers_guide.html) - To create/organize documents (spreadsheets)

Unless you actually want to display a web page, I would advice against using UIWebView. HTTP requests against API's are usually made using NSURLRequest and NSURLConnection. They give you complete control over the request and response handling.

While a custom implementation written yourself against the documents/spreadsheets API could suffice, most Google API's are an implementation of the Google Data protocol. This protocol has multiple libraries available that take care of the actual implementation on top of NSURLRequest.

A client library and sample code is available to [access the spreadsheets API using Objective-C](http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/code.html).

Comment: I could not find anything on Accessing google docs using objective c using the link you have provided.